# Magento 2 Category Save No such entity with id = XXXX

Tags: magento2

I have used Magento 2.2.2 EE. I have Got the Error "No such entity with id = XXXX" while saving the category.
I have Done some points to resolve this issue:

1. Remove all rows from `url_rewrite` table for non-existent categories
   and products.
2. Disable all the third party modules.
3. Re-indexing

   But still the issue persist.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue from my self. The issue is in the `url_rewrite` table. Product And Categories having deleted Categories URL in this table. Backed up `url_rewrite` table and search with error id and delete it.

SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_id` = XXXX;

SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `target_path` LIKE '%/category/XXXX%';

Delete the Records:

DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_id` = XXXX;

DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `target_path` LIKE '%/category/XXXX%';

Comment: In addition I had to do this `DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE metadata = '{"category_id":"XXXX"}';`